# How to initialize classes (not instances) in Python?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, class-method

I want to merge constraints from the current and inherited classes only once a class is loaded (not per object!).

```
class Domain(Validatable):

    constraints = {...}
```

To do this I defined a method `_initialize_class_not_instance` that should be called once for each class:

```
class Validatable:

    @classmethod
    def _initialize_class_not_instance(cls):
        # merge constraints from derived class and base classes
        pass

    __class__._initialize_class_not_instance() # doesn't work
    # Validatable._merge_constraints() # doesn't work too
```

The problem is that `__class__` doesn't exist in this context and `Validatable` is not defined too. But I want to avoid, that the user of my API has to call the initialize method explicitely or has to use an additional class decorator.

Any ideas how to initialize the class?

Comment: Note that classes **are** instances, usually they are instances of `type` but as @Ignacio has pointed out they can be instances of a custom subclass of `type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with a class decorator and without inheritance. This decorator merges the constraints of the current and inherited classes and overrides the `__init__` method:

```
def validatable(cls):

    # merge constraints from derived class and base classes here ...

    original_init = cls.__init__
    def init_to_insert(self, *args, **keywords):
        self.errors = {}
        original_init(self, *args, **keywords)   
    cls.__init__ = init_to_insert
    return cls
```

This is the key for my solution, since the decorator has to modify the class (merging constraints and inserting methods) and instances.

Answer (score 17):

Use a metaclass.

```
class MetaClass(type):
  def __init__(cls, name, bases, d):
    type.__init__(cls, name, bases, d)
    cls.foo = 42

class MyClass(object):
  __metaclass__ = MetaClass

print MyClass.foo
```

Comment: for the record, in python3, it's `MyClass(object, metaclass=MetaClass)`

Comment: Why do you need the MetaClass? Why not just put the statement "MyClass.foo = 42" after the definition of "MyClass"?

Comment: The point is to encapsulate the initialisation logic inside the class @ErelSegal-Halevi. OP explicitly mentions he does not want to have the user do any of the work. It should all happen inside the class.